Computing transformation matrices
$$  \text{let} \ \delta_x:P_2 \to \Bbb{R} \ \text{be given by} \ \delta_x(p)=p(x) \\
\text{let} \ B=\{(2)\} \ \text{be a basis for} \ \Bbb{R}^1 \\
\text{let} \ \epsilon = \{1,t,t^2\} \ \text{be a basis for} \ P_2 \subseteq \Bbb{R}[t]\\
\text{compute} \ [\delta_x]_\epsilon^B$$
The basis B is really throwing me off, so far i've got
$\delta_x(1) = 1 \\
\delta_x(t)=t \\
\delta_x(t^2) = t^2 \\$
I know i need to write each of these as linear combination of 2. I know $\delta_x(1)=1=2(\frac{1}{2}$) but i don't understand how to do that for t and $t^2$.

You have:

$\delta_x(1)=1=\frac12\times2$;
$\delta_x(t)=x=\frac x2\times2$;
$\delta_x(t^2)=x^2=\frac{x^2}2\times2$.

Therefore,$$[\delta_x]_\epsilon^B=\begin{bmatrix}\frac12&\frac x2&\frac{x^2}2\end{bmatrix}.$$

what you've said makes sense but my professor has given the answer as [$\frac{1}{2}$, 4, 8], but i don't know why

@confusedstudent your professor's answer is specifically for $x=8$, are you sure you aren't missing a part of the question?
